# Merge dev to stage but only specific commits

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, branch, cherry-pick

I want to merge my dev branch into stage but there are some commits that should not go to stage. One solution is to use cherry-pick but there are just too many commits to cherry-pick so it is not feasible. Is there any solution to take my changes from dev to stage without merging dev completely into stage.

I tried to use cherry pick but the first one I did, it had conflicts. There is no way I am doing this with 300 commits.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no magic wand for this. If you need only part of a 300 commits branch, you'll probably have to face a legion of conflicts. The underlying problem is the initial workflow decision which caused this extremely long-winded branch to grow separately, I guess.

Comment: You have these two long-living branches. And “stage” is a I guess one more degree of maturity compared to “dev”. If you can’t merge one of them into the other then what’s the point of (either one) of them? “dev” clearly is not maintained in a way which makes this “merge to a more mature branch” even possible. Your workflow is wrong.

Comment: If it's only a handful of commits you do not want to carry over from a list of 300 commits, you might consider creating a _separate_ branch from `dev` , revert the commits you do not want there and then merge **this branch** into `stage`.

Comment: `git rerere` may simplify the task of resolving the same conflicts over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this:

```
* fff (dev) fffffffff
* eee eeeeeeeee
* ddd ddddddddd
* ccc ccccccccc
| * bbb (stage) bbbbbbbbb
| * aaa aaaaaaaaa
|/
* zzz some common ancestor
```

Suppose you want to *merge* `dev` into `stage` but you *do not* want to include the changes from `eee` and `ddd`.

You could create a temporary branch and revert the commits from there:

```
git checkout -b temp dev
git revert eee
git revert ddd
```

Now you have this:

```
* hhh (temp) reversal of ddd
* ggg reversal of eee
* fff (dev) fffffffff
* eee eeeeeeeee
* ddd ddddddddd
* ccc ccccccccc
| * bbb (stage) bbbbbbbbb
| * aaa aaaaaaaaa
|/
* zzz some common ancestor
```

Now, we proceed to merge into `stage`:

```
git checkout stage
git merge temp
```

And we get this:

```
* iii (stage) merge of temp
|\
* | hhh (temp) reversal of ddd
* | ggg reversal of eee
* | fff (dev) fffffffff
* | eee eeeeeeeee
* | ddd ddddddddd
* | ccc ccccccccc
| * bbb bbbbbbbbb
| * aaa aaaaaaaaa
|/
* zzz some common ancestor
```

Now, time has gone by and `dev` has more commits:

```
* kkk (dev) yet more work in dev
* jjj more work in dev
| * iii (stage) merge of temp
| |\
| * | hhh (temp) reversal of ddd
| * | ggg reversal of eee
|/ /
* | fff fffffffff
* | eee eeeeeeeee
* | ddd ddddddddd
* | ccc ccccccccc
| * bbb bbbbbbbbb
| * aaa aaaaaaaaa
|/
* zzz some common ancestor
```

Say that at this point, you consider that you want to merge `dev`  again into `stage` and *now* that you are merging the full branch, you would expect to see the changes from `ddd`  and `eee` show up in the branch, right? Well.... **not really**... that can't happen because those commits are *already* merged into `stage`. You can see that the commits are already in the history of `stage`... another to look at it is by looking at the last common ancestor between `stage`  and `dev`... where is it? It's `fff` and only commits *past* this commit will be considered on the merge... `ddd`  and `eee`  are **not** past `fff`  and so you are out of luck..... you won't see those changes show up.... **unless** you come up with a magic trick.... you can undo the reversal that you did in `temp` and merge it back into `dev`... something like[1]:

```
git checkout temp
git revert hhh # reapply changes from ddd
git revert ggg # reapply changes from eee
git checkout dev
git merge -m "Undoing the reversal of ddd and eee" temp
```

And now you have a chart like this:

```
* nnn (dev) Undoing the reversal of ddd and eee
|\
|  \
|   * mmm (temp) Reversal of ggg # just like reapplying eee
|   * lll Reversal of hhh # just like reapplying ddd
*   | kkk yet more work in dev
*   | jjj more work in dev
| * | iii (stage) merge of temp
| |\|
| * | hhh reversal of ddd
| * | ggg reversal of eee
|/ /
* | fff fffffffff
* | eee eeeeeeeee
* | ddd ddddddddd
* | ccc ccccccccc
| * bbb bbbbbbbbb
| * aaa aaaaaaaaa
|/
* zzz some common ancestor
```

And now, starting from the same common ancestor between `dev`  and `stage`, we have the changes from `ddd` and `eee` **reapplied** so when you merge, the changes **will** show up.

[1] The reversal of all those commits could have been done with just a single command, instead of having multiple `git revert`:

```
git checkout temp
git restore --worktree --index --source fff -- . # the commit before the first revert we did
git commit -m "Reapplying all commits we reverted... in a single shot"
```